# NEW operator doesn't work in after trigger in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

In postgresql 8.4.11, this trigger doens't work. After an update, the field modified_date is not updated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  upd_date() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $test$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  NEW.modified_date := clock_timestamp();
  RETURN new;
END;
$test$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'; 

CREATE TRIGGER myTable_upd_date
after update 
ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE upd_date();
```

How to resolve this problem? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change values in an **after** trigger because that is fired, well, *after* the values have been persisted.

You need to change that to a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Make the trigger fire before update rather than after.